# Ошибка при загрузке расширений

Tags: windows, php, openserver

При любой попытке запуска php всплывает предупреждение,
гласящее следующее:

```
Warning: Php Startup: unable to load dynamic library 'c:\php\php_openssl.dll' - the specified module could not be found
```

И так, кроме `openssl`, для `php_curl`, `php_mysql`, `php_pdo_mysql`.

А весь цимес в том, что Диска С у меня нет вовсе, и интерпретатор php лежит по адресу `E:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-5.5.6`.

Никак не могу взять в толк, что происходит.

Comment: @Mamburu эти расширения встроены уже, пользуюсь OpenServer с момента его появления, подобные ошибки не встречал.

Answer (score 1):

[[[[[[@Mamburu](/users/20142/mamburu)](/users/20142/mamburu)](/users/20142/mamburu)](/users/20142/mamburu)](/users/20142/mamburu)](/users/20142/mamburu), вам надо отредактировать php.ini, т.к. это скорее всего он указывает такие пути до расширений. Для нормальной работы должно быть достаточно просто сменить `c:\` на `E:\OpenServer\modules\`

**Обновление**

[[[[[[@Mamburu](/users/20142/mamburu)](/users/20142/mamburu)](/users/20142/mamburu)](/users/20142/mamburu)](/users/20142/mamburu)](/users/20142/mamburu), строго говоря, пути к расширения не только в не могут быть, проверьте еще C:\php. По-хорошему вообще надо искать файлы по этой строчке.

**Обновление 2**

[[[[[[@Mamburu](/users/20142/mamburu)](/users/20142/mamburu)](/users/20142/mamburu)](/users/20142/mamburu)](/users/20142/mamburu)](/users/20142/mamburu), ну тогда не проверяйте. Ищите по тексту, какой-то файл ссылается на расширение этим адресом. Возможно, и не напрямую, просто extension dir может быть указан как C:\php

Comment: php.ini в порядке, либо же я редактирую не тот, что странно.

Comment: У меня ведь и диска-то такого нет. )